# JavaScript running the wrong event listener function

Tags: javascript, html

When I upload a file to the `card2` html div, I would expect the `FileUpload2` javascript function to run instead of `FileUpload`. But my output is running `console.log("Hello");` instead of `console.log("World");` indicating that the `FileUpload` function is called, not `FileUpload2`

```js
var imgPreview = document.getElementById('img-preview');
var fileUpload = document.getElementById('file-upload');

var imgPreview2 = document.getElementById('img-preview2');
var fileUpload2 = document.getElementById('file-upload2');

fileUpload.addEventListener('change', function(event){
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET);
        axios({
            url: CLOUDINAY_URL,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: formData
        }).then(function(res){
            console.log("Hello");
            console.log(res);
            imgPreview.src = res.data.secure_url;
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    });

    fileUpload2.addEventListener('change', function(event){
        var file2 = event.target.files[0];
        var formData2 = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file2);
        formData.append('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET2);
        axios({
            url: CLOUDINAY_URL,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: formData2
        }).then(function(res){
            console.log("World");
            console.log(res);
            imgPreview2.src = res.data.secure_url;
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <img  src="{{url_for('static', filename='css/images/mount2.png')}}" id="img-preview" />
    <label class="file-upload-container" for="file-upload">
        <input id="file-upload" type="file" style="display:none;">

    </label>
</div>
<div class="card2">
    <img  src="{{url_for('static', filename='css/images/mount2.png')}}" id="img-preview2" />
    <label class="file-upload-container2" for="file-upload">
        <input id="file-upload2" type="file" style="display:none;">

    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<label class="file-upload-container2" for="file-upload">
```

to

```
<label class="file-upload-container2" for="file-upload2">
```